# Interactive sort fields display in page header in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with 10 columns and all these columns are sortable. my problem is if a used select one or more column i want to show in the report header that column X and y has been sorted and the sort direction

the reason i want to show this is because at the time of printing the report, the sort indicator is not printed

Thanks in advance